# How are CommunityTemplateDefinition image references made?

Tags: lightning-community, gack, experience-cloud, community-template, experience-bundle

I am getting a gack when creating a new community based on my community template so am looking at the template's content to try to see what is wrong. There is an example of such a template in the [CommunityTemplateDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_communitytemplatedefinition.htm) documentation, and that includes this image reference:

```
<bundlesInfo>
    <image>siteAsset_2dbe594eb6794173af78da264cd6a4a7</image>
    <order>1</order>
    <title>Preview Image</title>
    <type>PreviewImage</type>
</bundlesInfo>
```

Where is that image located and how does "siteAsset_2dbe594eb6794173af78da264cd6a4a7" identify the image?

(In my org I can't see anything with a matching name.)

**PS**

I found the cause of the gack. The template somehow caused a custom setting in a separate managed package to self-initialize and that DML seems to be the cause the gack because pre-creating the custom setting org defaults avoids the problem. (Found this custom setting reference in the debug log.)

Comment: Could it be a built-in image that is part of the default configuration?

Comment: Hi @CasparHarmer, No they are screen shots of the template... not done by me.

Comment: @keith can we modify this siteAsset image if we want to change the image

Comment: Thanks I found that it's located under static resource so I was able to modify the image